# Is it ok to raise your rep only editing questions / answers?

Tags: discussion, reputation, edits

I've been here for a while and sometimes when I get bored at work I read questions/answers from other users. Once in a while they have unindented code, unposted images or some grammar issues. I wonder if is ok to raise your rep this way. Obviously I answer sometimes when I really feel "expert" to answer that question, but also enjoy reading and improving other people's answers.

**EDIT:** I didn't know there was a editing rep cap (1k). I think this is a good way to earn some rep while you get used to SO's dynamic.

Comment: It's ok. Just keep in mind that you can only get up to 1000 points via edits alone.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that :)

Comment: Or once you get to 2000.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sure! Why not? A lot of people often take a less technical role. Personally, I am no FGITW when it comes to programming questions, so a lot of my Stack Overflow rep is from edits. As long as the edits you are suggesting are valid edits that are not changing the question or answer, then you should be set.

This is the reason for the "Suggested Edit" review. It provides a way for higher rep. members to review what you suggest. As long as it is valid, we will approve it and you'll get your deserved +2. Trust me, if the powers that be didn't want you to have those +2 points, they wouldn't implement the feature.

Also, be mindful that the +2 for editing ends once you reach 2K rep.

Go ahead! Edit (valid edits only) away!

Comment: hahaha, "the powers that be". It's just that I hate to see unindented code and feel the need to edit :P

Comment: That's perfectly OK. Not to belabor the point, but ensure it's always valid edits you are posting and you should have no problems. Tidy code  floats my boat too, so I always change that when I get a chance.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, It is ok to edit other's post with valid editing. You can see the edit policy in [faq section](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#editing)

For editing we have limit of 1K posts only and also if your reputation is 2K then you will not get any reputation points ( +2 ) for any further editing.

Comment: I know is ok, my point is that I could get 10k rep just editing (Not that I'm going to edit 20000 questions/answers :P), so I want to know if you guys consider it good or bad.

Comment: @JhonAlx No you can't because there's a 1k limit from edits.

Comment: Well after 2K reputation you won't get any reputation point for editing posts.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that :)